# How to convert std::string to CV::String in C++?

Tags: .net, string, opencv, c++-cli, managed-c++

I am calling my own defined function in which I pass the std::string as argument of this function. I also need to give input to **cv::Mat cv::imread(const cv::String &filename, int flags=1);** And I can not give arguments as cv::String.

So I need to **convert std::string to cv::String** anyhow.

**Update:**

I have packaged above described function in a unmanaged DLL and calling it from a C# Console application  so it gives me bad memory allocation.

*I have tried to cast std::string in cv::String constructor but it didn't work.*

**Unmanaged C++ code (created DLL in Visual studio 2013)**

**MathFunc.h**

```
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

namespace MathFunc
 { 
   extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) double DoSomething(std::string imgPath); }

 }
```

**Mathfunc.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "MathFuncDll.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

namespace MathFunc
 {
  double DoSomething(std::string imgPath)
   {
    try{
        cv::Mat image;
        image = cv::imread(imgPath);
    }catch (exception &e){
        cout << "Error Occurred"<< e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

*This is the error I get when using:*

```
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 1345270332 bytes) in cv::OutOfMemoryError,
file C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52
```

So the string passed to this function is of `1345270325 characters long`

When I give image path as `image = cv::imread("C:/path_to_images/input_image.jpg");`, it works fine. No error occurs.

Does any one know how to correct this ?

Comment: Try passing `c_str()` of `std::string` as the argument.

Comment: or you could cast it http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d8f/classcv_1_1String.html#a8bbd0cc5d752437758918151afd9bb82

Comment: When you say " I can not give arguments as cv::String." what happens when you pass the argument (and let the compiler convert)?  What error message do you get.

Comment: Could you show the relevant code and error message?

Comment: @Arunmu  I have updated my question with code I tried. Please  look.

Comment: @Mavie Did you try to debug what's the value of `imgPath` inside `DoSomething`? And `DoSomething` is a C linkage function, I'm not sure, but use it with C++ `std::string` might cause the error...

Comment: @songyuanyao This is the output when I print the value of variable `imgPath` using `cout<<imgPath<<endl;`.       C:/path_to_images/input_image.jpg  § ╠2§     ♀δ6 ↑á§ ╠2§     L└§ ♀
↔└§ L└§ hδ6 ╤∙┼k♀3§ µ∙┼k,←n)╠2§ Φδ6     ≡2§     !└§ p # ↑á§ └τ~ ♀3§ µ∙┼k    ♀3§
╠2§     ¼δ6 °▀═k    ╕δ6 P√┼k╕δ6 YQ┘k^Q┘kⁿ←n)@ε6 Φδ6 └τ~ └τ~ L└§ ←¶‼Ç*   ♫   Φδ6
    |δ6 L∞6 t`§l|W+)`┤Ç α☺          ☺   ─┬n☻ ∞6 ù #     └τ~ L∞6  ∞6                               **and many more characters like this**

Comment: @Mavie It seems being corrupted. Change the type of `imgPath` to `const char*` might work.

Comment: @songyuanyao It didn't work. output beccame `╟Eⁿ☺`

Comment: @Mavie Sorry I can't figure out it either. Anyway it seems you asked the wrong question. The problem is not how to convert `std::string` to `cv::String`, is about how to pass a `std::string` to a C linkage function, and why passed string is corrupted.

Comment: I just had a _very_ weird issue with this. I literally could not track the line down as it was throwing in MSVC140's `algorithm.h`, and had to revert to a previous commit. After re-adding all my changes _carefully_ and one at a time, it didn't happen again. That makes me think of evil stuff like encoding errors from copied content and other error-message chicanery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [document](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d8f/classcv_1_1String.html#aba22f87619091a1b6a2899d0b45a3472), `cv::String` has a constructor taking one `std::string` as its parameter, which means `std::string` could be implicitly converted to `cv::String`.

Comment: I have updated my question with code I tried. Please look

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with using a `std::string` directly ?

`imread` works fine for me when I write something along the lines of

```
std::string filename = "Path/to/img.jpg";
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(filename);
```